# How to Not Show JQuery Modal to Klaviyo Subscribers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a JQuery Modal popup that works perfectly fine, but we need to add extra functionality to it. We need it to not show to already Klaviyo subscribers.

Here's the code for the popup

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://insideoutcreative.io/wp-content/themes/io-theme/css/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
<style>
div#ex1 {
height: 415px;
    max-width: 650px !important;
}
a.close-modal {
    display: none !important;
}
/*for background image*/
img.bg-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.close-btn {
    background: #da0000;
}
/*.img-txt {*/
/*    padding-top: 110px;*/
/*}*/
/*overrides klaviyo form*/
.kgtZbf.kgtZbf {
    align-items: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width:450px){
    .kgtZbf.kgtZbf {
    display: block;
}
.modal .gMGRIY.gMGRIY {
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.img-txt {
    width: 100%;
}
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      if (window.location.pathname == '/testing-closing-of-popup') {
    if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
        $(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){   
    $('#modalButton').trigger('click');
            }, 15000);
});
    }
};


});
</script>
<!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
<div id="ex1" class="modal text-center position-relative">
    <img src="https://kryptek.com/asset/5f7f6f5f102c7" width="100%" class="bg-img" />
<img src="https://kryptek.com/asset/5f7f6d2b25139" width="80%" class="img-txt position-relative float-left" style="padding-top:20px;" />
  <img src="https://kryptek.com/asset/5f7f5b678fb56" width="250px" height="auto" class="position-relative" />
  <div class="klaviyo-form-SXGhkE"></div>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close" class="position-relative close-btn text-white pl-4 pr-4 pt-1 pb-1">No Thank You, Close Popup</a>
</div>
<!-- Link to open the modal -->
<p style="position:fixed;z-index:-1;"><a id="modalButton" href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>
```

As said, the popup works fine, but I'm not sure how to add the extra functionality to only show it to 'new' people and not Klaviyo subscribers. You can view an example of the popup here: https://kryptek.com/testing-closing-of-popup

I tried chatting with them and all they did was send me to these articles about their API integration, which I didn't understand much.

Getting Started with the JavaScript API: https://www.klaviyo.com/docs/getting-started
Server-Side API Overview: https://www.klaviyo.com/docs

Any help is appreciated and if you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: I opened your example, Modal is showed only first time.
Is that correct?

Comment: @Pakawat Smutkyn, yes that is correct, if you see in the code, there is a cookie function using JavaScript to only show the modal once every 30 days after someone’s closed the modal. That is one working perfectly, I have no questions about that. What I need help is making it so it only shows to not Klaviyo subscribers.

Comment: You can check who is Klaviyo subscribers or not by ajax to your service then set the cookie the same way with close modal, This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After signing in, go to this URL: https://www.klaviyo.com/forms

Click on the form which is being displayed

Click on Target & Behavior

Scroll down to the targeting section you will see this option:

- Don't show to existing Klaviyo profiles

Select this and then existing user will not be able to see the form :-)

[image]